# How to start a new activity from item click in NavDrawer

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm a novice. I was just wondering how to start a new (pre-defined) activity from clicking one of the option items inside a navigation drawer? I have just completed a tutorial on how to make the NavDrawer. Here is what I have so far in my main activity (it's called `IntroActivity`)

**IntroActivity.java:**

```
public class IntroActivity extends Activity {

private String[] drawerListViewItems;
private ListView drawerListView;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);

    //Retrieve List items from strings.xml
    drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_items);

    //Retrieve ListView defined in intro_activity.xml
    drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    //Set the adapter for the list view
    drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_listview_item, drawerListViewItems));

    //App Icon
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, /* Host Activity */
            drawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* Image to replace "up" image*/
            R.string.drawer_open, /* Open drawer description*/
            R.string.drawer_close /* Close drawer description*/
            );

    //Set actionBarDrawerToggle as the DrawerListener
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //ADD SHADOW TO THE RIGHT EDGE OF DRAWER
    drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

    //Responding to clicks implementation:
    drawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Sync the toggle state after onRestart... has occurred
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.intro, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //Call ActionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(),
            //If it returns true, then it has handles the app icon touch event
            if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        //I WOULD LIKE TO REPLACE THE FOLLOWING CODE WITH SOMETHING 
        //THAT CAN START A NEW ACTIVITY
        /*Toast.makeText(IntroActivity.this, ((TextView)view).getText(), 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); */

        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerListView);
    }
}

}
```

Thanks if you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(IntroActivity.this, YourNewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

where `YourNewActivity` is the activity you want to start

Comment: I tried that but after the =, on "newIntent", it tells me: "The method 'newIntent(IntroActivity, Class....)' is undefined for the type 'Intro Activity.DrawerItemClickListener'.

Comment: its "new Intent" not "newIntent". Note the space between new and Intent